# Extract metadata from database using python?

Tags: python, django, database-metadata

I have looked for an answer to this question, but very was able to find very little. I want to extract the names of the tables, references between them, column names so I can graphically visualize that information. I need to this in a Django project.

Since I am a newbie to python I would like to know if there is some kind of API to do this type of thing.

**Edit**

I have created a model which consists Node, Attribute and Link. Node has attributes, while Link has fields parent_node and child_node. What I want is to connect to a database, read the metadata by which I mean: Table names, Column names and Foreign key constraints. Then I could properly put this data in the model I have created.

Comment: It is not really clear to me what you want. You want to visualize *foreign key* constraints?

Comment: I have created a model which consists Node, Attribute and Link. Node has attributes, while Link has fields parent_node and child_node. What I want is to connect to a database, read the metadata by which I mean:
Table names, Column names and Foreign key constraints. Then I could properly put this data in the model I have created. Hope it is clearer now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `inspectdb`command, with this django reads your database and create models for each table and if your database has relations you get also in django. You can see more info [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/legacy-databases/#auto-generate-the-models).

```
python manage.py inspectdb
```

Comment: This doesn't exactly help me since it creates a model, what I need is basically string table and column names and information about which table references another table through the foreign key constraint.